# Error trying to call scripts from Analysis Services Stored Procedure Project assembly

Tags: sql-server, security, ssas, sql-server-2014, .net-assembly

I'm trying to build out reports for Auditing SQL Server Analysis Services. Instead of reinventing the wheel, I'm attempting to bring together solutions that already exist into something more robust for my businesses purposes.

One of the major components to this solution that I'm piecing together uses the Analysis Services Stored Procedure Project, more information can be found at this link: https://asstoredprocedures.github.io/ASStoredProcedures/

This project relies on installing an assembly to the desired SSAS instance or specific database.

After installing this assembly, following the given install instructions, I continually run into an error letting me know that it cannot find or use an associated file. Here's the error:

> Query (1, 6) Execution of the managed stored procedure
>   DiscoverXmlMetadataFull failed with the following error: Exception has
>   been thrown by the target of an invocation.Could not load file or
>   assembly 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Xmla, Version=10.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..

From my research, the normal solution given to this problem is to delete or uninstall the assembly, then to reinstall it. The next solution give is to try installing other versions of the assembly until you find one that works. The other solution is to make sure the account you're using has sysadmin access.

Well, I've tried all of these and none of them are working to solve the issue.

One thing I found strange that I made note of, I downloaded the SQL Server 2014 solution, which would be version 12. Something I'm seeing is that no matter what version of the assembly (dll) that I use, I still end up seeing that the error says the version is 10. But if I get into the dll with a tool like JetBrains dotPeak or if I download the code directly from GitHub, I can see that inside of the reference object labeled with version 10 it is actually correctly pointing to version 12. So maybe it's not a real issue, just a bad practice with naming/labeling.

Another thing I've noticed is when I'm creating a new assembly, I immediately can go into the details section (next to the debug checkbox) and try viewing different objects in the assembly. Right away some of these objects are listed as unavailable, not working with permissions, not found. Even though they're all inside the same dll. This makes me believe that certain dependent objects located in other folder locations is the real problem. But I don't know how to confirm this or fix it.

Any advice on what else I could try to get this assembly working would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Can you double check the Assemblies folder in SSMS under the SSAS database you are connecting to? I'm wondering if you have the ASSP assembly under the database and also under the server. The database one would win.

Comment: I only have it under the server level.